# What's the best way to store a maya api object inside an std::map that will never become stale? c++

Tags: c++, api, maya

I have an std::map that I'm using to cache some objects info and I will be using that later, I'd like to have my object as a key so it takes as little time as possible to access it.

I was thinking of converting the UUID to string but I realised you can actually end up with duplicated uuids if the object gets brought to the scene as a reference multiple times.

I've also tried with adding an MDagPath but it won't allow me to store that into an std::map. I imagine I'd have to make it hashable but I can't think of a way to do that safely. Using a name I also think it's a big nono since it can be renamed.

Thanks for the help. I hope I was clear enough with my problem.

Comment: Can't you use MObjects?

Comment: I can't since it's unhashable by default, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @MyHornCanPierceTheSky `std::map` doesn't use any hash because it's a sorted dictionary. Only `std::unordered_map` is a hash map

Answer (score 0):

std::map isn't a hash map *(you'd want unordered_map for that)*. As for adding an MDagPath to a std::map, you could do it via something along these lines:

```cpp
// I don't think this is defined for dagpath?
// So you should be able to define it for MDagPath. 
static inline bool operator < (const MDagPath& a, const MDagPath& b) {
  return a.fullPathName() < b.fullPathName();
}

std::map<MDagPath, MyObjectInfo> myMap;
```

Alternatively, if you want to generate a lookup based on the object, then you can use MObjectHandle. It may still go stale, but at least it has the isAlive() and isValid() methods to tell you when it is stale.

You could insert that into an unordered_map

```cpp
namespace std {

  // override the std::hash for the MObjectHandle
  template <>
  struct hash< MObjectHandle >
  {
    std::size_t operator()(const MObjectHandle& k) const
    {
      return k.hashCode();
    }
  };
}

std::unordered_map<MObjectHandle, MyObjectInfo> myMap;
```

*(code is untested - I don't have access to Maya at the moment)*